# Recursive Search with Array-Based Implementation

Tags: c++, recursion

I'am having some trouble with this program and I can not figure what I'am doing wrong; the program is supposed to be a recursive search program, however some of the functions are not being called correctly (or at all). The problem seems to center around the "bin_search" portion, and again an error pops up on the "int data [size]" portion, saying "Variable-sized object may not be initialized". Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
# include <iostream> // Allows program to perform input and output
using std::cout; // program uses cout
using std::cin; // program uses cin



int bin_search ( int data[], int left, int right, int key, int NOT_FOUND)
{
 // calculate the index to search
 int index = ( ( ( key - data[ left ]) / ( data[ right ] - data[ left] ) )* (right - left)         ) + left;
 // terminating condition
 if ( data[index] == key )
 return key;
 // terminating condition
 if ( left >= right )
 return NOT_FOUND;
 // search recursively
 if ( key < data[index] )
 return bin_search ( data, left, index-1, key );
 else
 return bin_search ( data, index + 1, right, key );
}
    // end function bin search

int main()
{
 // function main begins program execution
  int size = 10;
  int bin;
  int data[size] = {0, 7, 12, 23, 44, 335, 426, 477, 658, 921};
  int key = 23;
 // let the user know about the program
 cout << "\n\n A program to search an element recursively.";
 // search and print the results to the user
 if ( bin_search( data, 0, size-1, key ) == key )
 cout << "\n\n\tThe key was found.";
 else
 cout << "\n\n\tThe key was not found.";
 // let the screen wait to see the output
 cout << "\n\n\t";
 system( "pause" );
 return 0; // indicate program executed successfully
 // end of function, main
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A few notes:

1. When there are `n` elements, you want to have `n + 1` positions! This way you can easily deal with an empty sequence and there is an obvious result to return if something isn't found.
2. Your computation to locate the `index` to check is far to complicated. All you want is to find the middle position of the sequence to search. The `key` is certainly not part of this computation.
3. You need to deal with the situation that the sequence is empty.
4. Personally, I wouldn't implement a binary search recursively, especially if the call isn't tail-recursive.
5. When talking about personal preferences, I would implement it in terms of iterators anyway.

Comment: + the elephant in the room, the array declaration is invalid.